# run_example function in devtools works but check function fails when running examples

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I am developing a package and I am using devtools to check the functionality of the package. I am getting some contradictory results with two of the functions from devtools. When I use `devtools::run_example` function to check if the examples are working it finishes without any error. However when I use `devtools::check` it fails in the checking examples step, i.e.

```
* using R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* using options ‘--no-manual --as-cran’
* checking for file ‘scmeth/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘scmeth’ version ‘0.99.2’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘scmeth’ can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking ‘build’ directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... OK
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
* checking package subdirectories ... OK
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking dependencies in R code ... OK
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK
* checking foreign function calls ... OK
* checking R code for possible problems ... OK
* checking Rd files ... OK
* checking Rd metadata ... OK
* checking Rd line widths ... OK
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking installed files from ‘inst/doc’ ... OK
* checking files in ‘vignettes’ ... OK
* checking examples ... ERROR
```

So I am not sure why I am getting contradictory results from these two functions. In particular the `check` function complains that it couldn't find a certain function from a library that I import in the DESCRIPTION file.

Package description is below

```
Version: 0.99.2
Depends: R (>= 3.4.0)
Imports:
  ggplot2,
  knitr,
  bsseq,
  AnnotationHub,
  Repitools,
  GenomicRanges,
  reshape2,
  stats,
  utils,
  BSgenome,
  DelayedArray,
  annotatr(>= 1.2.1),
  SummarizedExperiment,
  GenomeInfoDb
Suggests:
  rmarkdown,
  BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10,
  BSgenome.Hsapiens.NCBI.GRCh38,
  Biobase,
  BiocGenerics,
  Biostrings,
  DT
```

This is a bioconductor package and the code fails saying `Error in builtin_genomes() : could not find function "builtin_genomes"`

Which is a function in annotatr package and I import it in my description.

Comment: is your package available on github? If not, you should at least provide the content of the DESCRIPTION file so we can see the packages you are using, and the code of the example that fails during the check.

Comment: @sinQueso It is not in github, I have added the description it essentially fails saying it couldn't identify a function but in fact it a s function in a package that I import.